# Python Attr: Converter that uses other attributes?

Tags: python-attrs

Is there a way in Python attrs for a converter to reference attributes in self?  Right now I'm using `__attr_post_init__` but it feels like a sin.

```py
@attrs
class WindowLayout(object):
    panel_xxyy_boxes = attrib(type=Dict[str, Tuple[int, int, int, int]])
    size = attrib(type=Tuple[int, int], default=None)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        if self.size is None:
            self.size = (max(x for _, x, _, _ in self.panel_xxyy_boxes.values()), max(y for _, _, _, y in self.panel_xxyy_boxes.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your “sin” is based on a misconception. :)

“Converting” a missing argument into a computed value is what attrs has defaults for.

Based on your example, something like this should work:

```py
@attrs
class WindowLayout(object):
    panel_xxyy_boxes = attrib(type=Dict[str, Tuple[int, int, int, int]])
    size = attrib(type=Tuple[int, int])

    @size.default
    def _size_default(self):
        return (max(x for _, x, _, _ in self.panel_xxyy_boxes.values()), max(y for _, _, _, y in self.panel_xxyy_boxes.values()))
```

Comment: Oh I know default, but I also want to be able to fall back on the default size if I pass in None.  ie it should pass `assert WindowLayout(panel_xxyy_boxes, size=None).size==(max(x for _, x, _, _ in self.panel_xxyy_boxes.values()), max(y for _, _, _, y in panel_xxyy_boxes.values()))`. I suppose I could, from the calling-sight, do `WindowLayout(panel_xxyy_boxes, **({'size': size} if size is not None else {}))` but that seems like an even greater sin.

Comment: Or maybe this should just be a feature request for a `@attibute_name.converter` decorator.